# Creating an android app with Sencha Touch 2 builder

Tags: android, sencha-touch-2

I'm attempting to build an app using the Sencha Touch 2 builder tools. I have a basic app, I just want to test out creating an app so I can do it when I need to.

I've got the sencha tools, the android SDK etc

I've got to the point when you run

```
sencha package build <configfile.json>
```

in the command line. After several tries I've got to the point where it seems to accept the command, but it doesn't DO anything, doesn't create an app, doesn't display anything in command line, nothing.

I believe I'm missing something but can't think what.

This is my config file:

```
{
"applicationName":"Test_app",
"applicationId":"com.testing.test_App",
"versionString":"1.0",
"iconName:":"resources\icons\Icon.png",
"inputPath":"\",
"outputPath":"C:\Users\rc\Android Development\Completed Apps",
"configuration":"Debug",
"platform":"Android",
"deviceType":"Universal",
"certificatePath":"C:\Users\rc\Android Development\Keystore\Test App\my-release-key.keystore",
"certificateAlias":"Test_app",
"sdkPath":"C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk",
"orientations": [
    "portrait",
    "landscapeLeft",
    "landscapeRight",
    "portraitUpsideDown"
]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to solve this by using the following command instead:

```
sencha app build native
```

I will continue to look at the original way to understand it didn't work but this does work for now.

Answer (score 1):

Your config file looks OK to me.

It can take a very long time for that command to respond - many minutes, on my machine here.  It seems to buffer all its output until it completes.  You can tell whether it really is doing something or not by watching the contents of the output path: you should see files and folders being created and destroyed.